# Mapbox GL JS - Change the color of selected 3D buildings

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

in my database I have ID numbers (mapbox) of about a million buildings, each building is associated with a category.
Buildings are scattered all over the world.
There can be many more buildings, so the data should be downloaded dynamically (json, geojson, etc.).

I would like to change the color of 3D buildings (fill-extrusion-color) depending on the category and add an icon next to it.

I have been browsing the documentation but I am not able to combine it into a solution.

I am asking for help as I should solve this problem.

Currently, it only controls color like this:

```
'fill-extrusion-color': [ "case", [ "! =", ["get", "min_height"], 0 ], "hsl (224, 18%, 56%)", [ "match", ["get", "type"], ["building: part"], true, false ], "hsl (224, 25%, 38%)", [ "interpolate", ["linear"], ["get", "height"], 0, "hsl (224.47%, 29%)", twenty, "hsl (224.61%, 33%)", 50, "hsl (224.53%, 48%)", 400, "hsl (224, 83%, 72%)" ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
'fill-extrusion-color':
  [ "case", 
    [ "!=", ["get", "min_height"], 0 ], 
    "#7b85a3", 
    [ "match",
       ["get", "type"], 
       ["building: part"],
       true,
       false
    ], 
    "#495679", 
    [ "interpolate",
      ["linear"], 
      ["get", "height"], 
      0, "hsl (224, 47%, 29%)", 
      12, "hsl (224, 61%, 33%)", 
      50, "hsl (224, 53%, 48%)", 
      400, "hsl (224, 83%, 72%)"
    ]
  ]
```